# Excel - Function To Count All Strings In Range

Tags: excel, string, function, count, formula

I'm looking for a function that would count all of the different occcurrences of different strings within a range. It would go through an input range, cell by cell and, for each unique value it finds, it would count the number of occurrences of that value in the range.

So, for example, if I were to run it on this range:

[image]

I would get this result:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: use a pivot table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easiest to create a pivot table, which will create the uniques list and the count:

Put the string column in both the rows and the values.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I know little about Pivot tables - your solution works perfectly for me, however. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is with `=COUNTIF()` function.

The first argument it takes is the data range, the second - the value it will be seeking. So, for your example, the cells to count the Hellos, Goodbyes and Seeyas should look like that:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A6, "Hello")
=COUNTIF(A1:A6, "Goodbye")
=COUNTIF(A1:A6, "See ya")
```

Comment: I'm aware of the countif and countifs functions. I want this to be done automatically, without me having to fill the cells with various versions of the countif function